# Android Google Pay API PayButton becomes invisible after couple of seconds

Tags: android, react-native, google-api, android-appcompat, google-pay

I'm trying to integrate Google Pay API's native [PayButton](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/tutorial#add-button) with my React Native app, and I thought everything was fine with this Android React Native bridge:

```
public class GooglePayButtonManager extends SimpleViewManager<PayButton> {
    public static final String REACT_CLASS = "GooglePayButton";
    ReactApplicationContext mCallerContext;

    public GooglePayButtonManager(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        mCallerContext = reactContext;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return REACT_CLASS;
    }

    private int theme = ButtonConstants.ButtonTheme.DARK;
    private int type = ButtonConstants.ButtonType.BUY;
    private int cornerRadius = 20;

    @Override
    protected PayButton createViewInstance(@NonNull ThemedReactContext themedReactContext) {
        PayButton button = new PayButton(themedReactContext);
        button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            WritableMap map = Arguments.createMap();
                themedReactContext.getJSModule(RCTEventEmitter.class).receiveEvent(v.getId(), "onPress", map);
        });
        buildButton(button);
        return button;
    }

    private void buildButton(PayButton button) {
        button.initialize(ButtonOptions.newBuilder()
                .setButtonTheme(theme)
                .setButtonType(type)
                .setCornerRadius(cornerRadius)
                .setAllowedPaymentMethods("[]")
                .build());
    }
}
```

But now I've noticed that it only works with this variation of the Button, which I get during the first launch of the app:

[image: working Gpay button]

Then after concurrent launches of the same app, I get this button just for a couple of seconds:
[image]

afterwards it just becomes invisible, but is still clickable. If I reinstall the app I get the first version again, and works as normal, then same thing happens after restart.

Does anyone know what could cause this? Google Pay's Gradle package version is 19.2.1, React Native version 0.73.2.

One thing I've noticed is that with both versions I get this error in Logcat when PayButton's `.initialize()` is called:
`View class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView is an AppCompat widget that can only be used with a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant).` Which is strange because the theme is correctly defined, being a descendant of AppCompat. Also I don't get the error if I return the actual AppCompatTextView instead of the PayButton from the same class.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: after actually passing proper `allowedPaymentMethods` as mentioned by @Domi, the button no longer disappears. But now when button loads, instead of card's digits, empty space is displayed, with no particular errors in LogCat:

[image: Button with empty space]

EDIT2: I'm tearing my hair over this - I found out when the above empty digits variant is rendered, if I change anything in the component's `style` prop from React Native side (e.g. change `width` from 100% to 101%) and re-bundle again, the button is then rendered correctly with the digits :) But I cannot recreate it to render correctly without re-bundling anything.

Comment: Yes, showing dynamic data (last 4 digits of the card) currently only works for the "BUY" button type. Make sure to properly set the allowedPaymentMethods for this to work. What do you mean with "afterwards it just becomes invisible"?

Comment: @Domi thanks, passing proper `allowedPaymentMethods` instead of empty array helped, the button no longer disappears. However, now when button loads, empty digits are displayed (attached img to post). Do you know why?

Comment: I don't. this is interesting. Are you able to provide a full reproducer?

Comment: @Domi don't have much time to make a reproducer now unfortunately :/ I contacted GPay support over this, in the meanwhile using Pay button type, which works fine

Comment: Yeah. They reached out to me  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is a React Native issue/bug. For more details see here:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17968

As a workaround you could wrap the Google Pay `PayButton` and then trigger `measure()` and `layout()` by overwriting `requestLayout()` in your wrapper:

```java
@Override
public void requestLayout() {
  super.requestLayout();
  post(measureAndLayout);
}

private final Runnable measureAndLayout =
    () -> {
        measure(
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getHeight(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        layout(getLeft(), getTop(), getRight(), getBottom());
    };
```

Check how Stripe solved this for their react native component (Kotlin):

- [Wrapper implementation](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/blob/dc18e367af9db9dec0918840d20da05095d6e223/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativestripesdk/GooglePayButtonView.kt#L93)
- [GooglePayButtonManager implementation](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/blob/dc18e367af9db9dec0918840d20da05095d6e223/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativestripesdk/GooglePayButtonManager.kt)

**Update**:

In the meantime Google Pay released a [version](https://github.com/google-pay/react-native-make-payment/pull/15) of their button for react native. See [here](https://github.com/google-pay/react-native-make-payment/blob/main/example/src/App.jsx#L135) for an example.